# Não consigo executar o laço e obter o valor final dos itens

Tags: python

Não consigo fazer com que o laço volte a opcao para pedir mais alguma coisa.
E o break é para colocar em cada elif?
E como vou conseguir o valor final dos produtos, como crio uma variavel que vá acumulando o valor de todos os itens pedidos?[[image: Imagem do código][1]]

Você e sua equipe de programadores foram contratados para desenvolver um app de vendas para uma lanchonete. Você ficou com a parte de desenvolver a interface do cliente para retirada do produto. A lanchonete possui seguinte tabela de produtos listados com sua descrição, códigos e valores:
Regras: Elabore um programa em Python que:

1. Entre com o código do produto desejado;
2. Pergunte se o cliente quer pedir mais alguma coisa (se sim repetir o passo item 2. Caso contrário ir para próximo passo);
3. Encerre a conta do cliente com o valor total;
4. Deve-se utilizar estruturas if, elif e else (EXIGÊNCIA 1 de 3);
5. Se a pessoa digitar um NÚMERO diferente dos da tabela printar na tela:‘opção inválida’ e voltar para o menu (EXIGÊNCIA 2 de 3);
6. Deve-se utilizar while, break, continue (EXIGÊNCIA 3 de 3);o (DICA: utilizar o continue dentro else que verifica a opção inválida)o (DICA: utilizar o break dentro elif que verifica a opção sair)

```
#Cardápio expositivo da lanchonete
print('Bem Vindo a Lanchonete da Renata de Andrade Sousa.') #Nome do aluno.
print('**************** Cardápio ***************')
print('| Código |       Descrição       | Valor |')
print('|   100  |    Cachorro Quente    |  9,00 |')
print('|   101  | Cachorro Quente Duplo | 11,00 |')
print('|   102  |         X-Egg         | 12,00 |')
print('|   103  |        X-Salada       | 12,00 |')
print('|   104  |        X-Bacon        | 14,00 |')
print('|   105  |         X-Tudo        | 17,00 |')
print('|   200  |  Refrigerante Lata    |  5,00 |')
print('|   201  |      Chá Gelado       |  4,00 |')
#Valor unitário dos itens começa aqui
cachorro_quente = 9
cachorro_qduplo = 11
x_egg = 12
x_salada = 12
x_bacon = 14
x_tudo = 17
refri = 5
cha = 4
#Valor unitário dos itens termina aqui

opcao = int(input('Deseja pedir mais alguma coisa? \n1 - Sim\n2 - Não\n'))
#Repetir enquanto opção digitada seja igual a 1
while(opcao == 1):
#Escolha do item pelo código dentro dos if, elif, seguindo a descrição da tabela Cardápio.
    codigo = int(input('Entre com o código referente ao pedido:'))
    if codigo == 100:
        print('Você pediu um Cachorro Quente no valor de R$ {:.2f}'.format(cachorro_quente))
    elif codigo == 101:
        print('Você pediu um Cachorro Quente Duplo no valor de R$ {:.2f}'.format(cachorro_qduplo))
    elif codigo == 102:
        print('Você pediu um X-Egg no valor de R$ {:.2f}'.format(x_egg))
    elif codigo == 103:
        print('Você pediu um X-Salada no valor de R$ {:.2f}'.format(x_salada))
    elif codigo == 104:
        print('Você pediu um X-Bacon no valor de R$ {:.2f}'.format(x_bacon))
    elif codigo == 105:
        print('Você pediu um X-Tudo no valor de R$ {:.2f}'.format(x_tudo))
    elif codigo == 200:
        print('Você pediu um Refrigerante Lata no valor de R$ {:.2f}'.format(refri))
    elif codigo == 201:
        print('Você pediu um Chá Gelado no valor de R$ {:.2f}'.format(cha))
#Mensagem de erro, caso cliente digite um código ausente no cardápio, retornando ao inicio do bloco de código.
    else:
        print('Opção Inválida! Digite o código novamente:')
        continue

print('O total a ser pago é: R$ ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você tem que usar o While True

Por exemplo:

```
while True:
    completa.append(int(input('Digite o código do produto que quer comprar: ')))
    resp = str(input('Quer continuar? [S/N]'))
    if resp in 'Nn':
        break
```

Com isso a partir dai você continua o seu desenvolvimento

Answer (score -3):

Fiz ai de uma maneira bem porca pq são quase 00, mas eu faria algo do tipo, ps: sou iniciante.

```
print('Bem Vindo a Lanchonete da Renata de Andrade Sousa.') #Nome do aluno.
print('**************** Cardápio ***************')
print('| Código |       Descrição       | Valor |')
print('|   100  |    Cachorro Quente    |  9,00 |')
print('|   101  | Cachorro Quente Duplo | 11,00 |')
print('|   102  |         X-Egg         | 12,00 |')
print('|   103  |        X-Salada       | 12,00 |')
print('|   104  |        X-Bacon        | 14,00 |')
print('|   105  |         X-Tudo        | 17,00 |')
print('|   200  |  Refrigerante Lata    |  5,00 |')
print('|   201  |      Chá Gelado       |  4,00 |')
#Valor unitário dos itens começa aqui
cachorro_quente = 9
cachorro_qduplo = 11
x_egg = 12
x_salada = 12
x_bacon = 14
x_tudo = 17
refri = 5
cha = 4
cont=1
t=0
pedido=list()
pergunta='S'
while pergunta=='S':
    if cont!=1:
        pergunta=str(input ('Deseja escolher outro produto? S/N  ')).upper().strip()[0]
    cont+=1
    if pergunta=='S':
        while True:
            cod=int(input ('Código do pedido: '))
            if cod==100:
                pedido.append (cod)
                t+=9
                break
            elif cod==101:
                pedido.append (cod)
                t+=11
                break
            elif cod==102:
                pedido.append (cod)
                t+=12
                break
            elif cod == 103:
                pedido.append (cod)
                t+=12
                break
            elif cod == 104:
                pedido.append (cod)
                t+=14
                break
            elif cod == 105:
                pedido.append (cod)
                t+=17
                break
            elif cod == 200:
                pedido.append (cod)
                t+=5
                break
            elif cod == 201:
                pedido.append (cod)
                t+=4
                break
            else:
                print('produto não localizado')


print(f'O total de sua compra deu {t:2f}')
```

Caso queira mostras os nomes no final, faria algo do gênero
tlvz

```
nome_pedido=list()
if 100 in pedido:
    nome_pedido.append('Cachorro quente')
#repete isso para todas opções
print(f'Os produtos '{nome_pedido} foram escolhidos.)
```